# Tracker.autorun and subscriptions from array

Tags: meteor

I registered three Tracker.autorun functions with collection from array: ['tags', 'allUsers', 'userGroups']

```
formObj.collections.forEach(collection => {
  Tracker.autorun(() => {
    const handle = Meteor.subscribe(collection);

    if (handle.ready()) {
      dispatch(collectionIsReady(formObj, collection));

      console.log(collection);

      if (_.isEqual(formObj.collections, formObj.loadedCollections)) {
        dispatch(collectionsAreReady(formObj));
        dispatch(formIsReady(formObj));
      }
    }
  });
});
```

If one of these collections changed the Tracker.autorun function is executed but only with the collection name of the last array item (console output: "userGroups"). What should i do to get the correct collection name?

thanks for your help

**Edit:**
There is no need to know the correct collection name.

Because of correctly executed autorun functions i additionally passed the computation (c) to collectionIsReady().

```
formObj.collections.forEach(collection => {
  Tracker.autorun((c) => {
    const handle = Meteor.subscribe(collection);

    if (handle.ready()) {
      dispatch(collectionIsReady(formObj, collection, c));

      if (_.isEqual(formObj.collections, formObj.loadedCollections)) {
        dispatch(collectionsAreReady(formObj));
        dispatch(formIsReady(formObj));
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: the first param to Meteor.subscribe should be the name of the collection, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, the parameter is the name of the collection.

Comment: @corvid he's passing in the collection name by looping over an array of collection names